# CodeIgniter Hooks to display content on all pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, hook

I have a sidebar displayed on all my websites pages the same content should be displayed each time:

- current cash
- username
- more info...

For the `username` I'm using the session within the regular controllers so that's alright but for the cash, I need to make a call to the database. I've tried to use hooks but I can't figure out how to display the info in the view (the variable is undefined).
I'm stuck when loading the session.

I get the message: `Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php` eventhough my session library is autoloaded and I added it one more time in the hook, just in case...

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation','pagination', 'template');
```

My hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'get_info_general',
                                'function' => 'get_info_general',
                                'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => ''
                                );
```

My get_info_general.php

```
class get_info_general extends CI_Controller{
        private $CI;

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');     
            $this->load->library('session');     
            $this->load->library('database');     
        }  
        function get_info_general(){
            $this->load->model('usersModel');
            $cash = $this->usersModel->check_cash_player();
            $data['cash'] = $cash;
        } }
```

In UsersModel:

```
public function check_cash_player(){                    
        $currentUserID = $this->usersModel->get_user_id();
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('cash')
            ->from('place')
            ->where('id_player', $currentUserID)
            ->get();
        return $query->row('cash');
    }
```

**UPDATE**:
After @alexander popov suggestion I changed the code to:

```
class get_info_general {
        private $CI;

        public function __construct() {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->helper('url');     
            $CI->load->library('session');   
        }  
        function get_info_general(){
            $this->load->model('usersModel');
            $cash = $this->usersModel->check_cash_player();
            $data['cash'] = $cash;
        } }
```

And I get: `Undefined property: get_info_general::$load`

**UPDATE 2:**
Using the code provided [here](http://viper-7.com/bAQifv) I don't get any error message and my page is displayed. However `$cash` is still undefined in my page. Adding the following code to get_info_general.php doesn't help:

```
$data['cash'] = $cash;
$data['main_content'] = 'loginForm';
        $this->load->view('templates/default',$data);
```

Comment: I don't think you need to inherit your hood from CI_Controller. Instead you can get instance of the controller using `get_instance()` function.

Comment: if I remove the `extends CI_Controller` I get the error: `Message: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent`

Comment: Also you need to remove `parent::__construct()` from the constructor.

Comment: I updated the question. still no luck

Comment: The session library is already loaded. try to use it like this `$this->CI->session->myData`. Check this sample [sample](http://viper-7.com/bAQifv)

Comment: Try changing the name of the method `get_info_general()` to something different - so it doesn't match the class name.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Codeigniter... @AlexanderPopov What should myData refer to?
Changing the name doesn't help.

Comment: `myData` is just a sample of variable stored in session. Do you receive the error `Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php` after the changes?

Comment: but my variable (cash) won't be stored in the session. I think the current problem is the Load `$cash = $this->usersModel->check_cash_player();`. I get the error `Undefined property: get_info_general::$load`

Comment: You should use this statement `$this->CI->load` to load the `usersModel`. Please, take a look at the sample I provided in one of the previous comments.

Comment: great! it helps solving the error message. I updated my question

Comment: Where do you want to use `$cash` variable? How do you pass it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108435/discussion-between-alexander-popov-and-remyremy).

Comment: I need to use it in one of my view (loginForm) which is a part of the sidebar, to tell the user `you have xxx$`. So far in my view I call it like that: `echo '.$cash;` but it's undefined. From a normal controller I usually pass it as mentioned in my latest update; but from this Hook I'm not sure how to do

Comment: the problem was solved using sessions to store $cash. And call the session from the controller to pass it to the view